# Adding Prefix Match to pg_search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, railscasts, pg-search

I am following [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/343-full-text-search-in-postgresql) Railscasts episode.

If I search "Kerber" it does return the right article. 
But if I search "Ke" it does not returns the same article.

There's a way to fix this?

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search, against: [:description, :about, :link, :twitterhandle, :builtby],
  using: {tsearch: {dictionary: "english"}}

  def self.text_search(query)
    if query.present?
      search(query)
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm the author and maintainer of pg_search.

You can add `prefix: true` to the configuration for the `:tsearch` search feature to have pg_search automatically add `:*` to the end of your queries.

https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#prefix-postgresql-84-and-newer-only

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search, against: [:description, :about, :link, :twitterhandle, :builtby],
  using: {tsearch: {prefix: true, dictionary: "english"}}

  def self.text_search(query)
    if query.present?
      search(query)
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Handy, thanks for following up on this. So many [tag:postgresql] questions about so many different toolkits, languages, etc... can't know the details of them all.

Answer (score 3):

That result makes sense to me. `Ke` and `Kerber` are different words so they don't match in full-text search.

Full-text search only does *stemming* - removing plurals, etc - so that `cats` matches `cat`. Even this isn't exactly smart - atypical plurals like `dice` aren't handled. It also only works for words recognised in the target language dictionary, so even if `Kerber` was the plural of `Ke` it wouldn't be stemmed when the language is set to `english`.

See the tsquery and tsvectors:

```
regress=> SELECT to_tsvector('Kerber'), to_tsquery('Kerber'), to_tsvector('ke'), to_tsquery('ke');
 to_tsvector | to_tsquery | to_tsvector | to_tsquery 
-------------+------------+-------------+------------
 'kerber':1  | 'kerber'   | 'ke':1      | 'ke'
(1 row)
```

and the matches:

```
regress=> SELECT to_tsvector('Kerber') @@ to_tsquery('Kerber'), to_tsvector('kerber') @@ to_tsquery('ke');
 ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------
 t        | f                                                                                                                                                                  
(1 row)
```

I suspect that you want a [tsearch prefix match](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES). This is expressed with a `:*` wildcard:

```
regress=> SELECT to_tsvector('kerber') @@ to_tsquery('ke:*');
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

This *only* works for prefix matching. It can have an impact on search efficiency, but I don't think it's a major one.

Comment: This is exactly what i meant. Adding Prefix Match to the Items model solved my issue. Thank you very much!